# Azure Communication Service user management

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I am reviewing ACS(Azure Communication Services) for our chat / video call feature and noticed that they don't provide a GUI management tool for registered users.

What should I do with this Identity management system where I want to restrict a certain user who is already registered?

Comment: Actually, looking at this again, this does seem to be about the Azure Communication Services API...I've voted to reopen, assuming that this is about the API.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Communication Service is identity agnostic (meaning that it does not store your identities but provides it's own identifiers). This means that you need to keep mapping between your identities and ACS identities. You can issue access token for the ACS identity, to give it permission to use calling or chat.

The restriction of the action is bind to your identity. Azure Communication Services managing access to the primitives such as calling and chatting. This means, that on your application level you have to design whether your identity can access given meeting. If your application decides to grant the permission to join the meeting, user can create/reuse access token and join the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "restrict". But, if you want to delete a created user, you can use the [API to delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/communicationidentity/delete) the identity object. At this time, there's no UI for this.

Comment: for the restriction, we provide telehealth and we want to make sure that only invited user can join the call. I know we can call that api to delete only if we know that specific user id. But I want to manage users in bulk like deleting users who is not active for months or etc.

Comment: Thanks for the context! I'll pass this to the team.